# Kafka transaction management at producer end

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I am looking for how Kafka behave when the producer is running in transaction.
I have a oracle database insert operations running in same transaction which rollback the changes if the transaction is rolled back.
How does Kafka producer behave in case of transaction rollback.

Will the message be rolled back or Kafka doesn't support rollback.

I know the JMS message are committed to queue only when transaction is committed. Looking for similar solutions if it is supported.

Note : Producer code is written using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update two systems

- update a record in your oracle database
- sending a event to apache kafka

This represents a challenge as you would like it to be atomic, either everything gets executed or nothing, otherwise you will end up with inconsistencies between your database and kafka.

- You might send a Kafka message even if the database transaction was rollbacked.
- Or the other way around (if you are sending the message just after the commit), you might commit the database transaction and crash (for some reason) just before sending the Kafka event.

One of the simplest solution is to use the outbox pattern:

- Let's say you want to update an order table and send orderEvent to kafka
- Instead of sending the event to kafka in the same transaction
- You can save it a database table (outbox) using the same transaction as the order update
- A separate process will read data from outbox table and make sure it's sent to kafka (using at least once semantic)
- Your consumer need to be idempotent.

In this post, I explain more in detail how to implement this solution

https://mirakl.tech/sending-kafka-message-in-a-transactional-way-34d6d19bb7b2

Answer (score 0):

RocketMQ provides a mechanism called "transactional messages" and includes a feature called "check" for handling the confirmation status of messages sent to RocketMQ.

When a producer sends a transactional message, RocketMQ returns a transaction ID. The producer needs to store this transaction ID along with the transaction status (committed or rolled back) in its local transaction log while performing the local transaction. Periodically, the producer needs to check the status of the transaction by sending a check request to RocketMQ.

Upon receiving the check request, RocketMQ will invoke the corresponding check listener registered by the producer. The check listener can then examine the local transaction status and respond to RocketMQ with the final confirmation status (commit or rollback) of the transaction. Based on the check response, RocketMQ will take appropriate actions to commit or rollback the transaction.

The check mechanism in RocketMQ ensures the reliability and consistency of transactional messages by allowing the producer to confirm the final status of a transaction.